# SimpleXMLElement affectation (pass properties in write context)

Tags: php, simplexml

I've got an issue with SimpleXML. Like in the official documentation, I want to do this :

```
<?php
include 'example.php';
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$movies->movie[0]->characters->character[0]->name = 'Miss Coder';

echo $movies->asXML();
?>
```

But my code is :

```
<?php
public function renderMarker($xml, &$html)
{
    $html = ((string) $html) . 'Text to add';
}
?>
```

with :

```
$html = object(SimpleXMLElement)#185 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "title"
  }
}
```

But when I do this, I've got `$html = string(12) "Text to add"` as a result.
Does anybody knows a workarround for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When, where and how is this `renderMarker()` invoked?

Comment: What do you expect to get from (string) $html? SimpleXMLElement objects are strange, and don't always behave the way you expect if you don't use them in the documented ways. Actually I'm surprised that var_dump or print_r or whatever you used gave you any structure at all.

Comment: renderMarker() is much more complicated, in fact it's recursive and called with a complete xml and html file.
`(string) $html` is the text between begin and end of xml marker.

Comment: From the provided code snippets it's very hard (at least for me) to imagine what you're trying to do/trying to achieve. Can you provide a small self-contained example script?

Comment: Yes, here it is :
I've got a piece of xml like that :`<title><getter class="ClassName" method="getName"/></title>`
And my html looked like that : `<h1 id="title"></h1>`.
I would like to add the text returned to the html marker : `<h1 id="title">Name !</h1>`

Comment: What do you want to get out of `$html` inside that function? I can see you want to get a string, but a string of what? Attribute? Tagname? The node`s text-value?

Comment: I wonder if it works how you would like to do it, I start to understand what you would like to do, but be careful, it might not work that way. I doubt that it's possible to pass those dynamic properties of SimpleXML by reference.

Comment: I agree with hakre, it's most likely better (or necessary) to use the DOM or maybe even XSLT for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to achieve does not work and there is no solution for that with SimpleXML.

Each SimpleXML object has dynamic properties. You access them as-if they were a property of an object, but infact, each time you access them, either the property's return value is given (reading) or something else is updated (writing).

However, if you pass such properties to a function like you did, you only passed the actual return value (from reading) and not the property itself.

Simpliefied example which does not work, because `$xml->title` is not passed as variable into the `set_property` function (there is no need to add a reference, it does not make a difference):

```
$xmlStr = '<root><title></title></root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

function set_property(&$prop)
{
   $prop = 'Test';
}

set_property($xml->title);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><title/></root>
```

As written, there is no easy workaround for it. One workaround is that you create yourself a SimpleXMLProperty object that you can pass around in function parameters:

```
/**
 * Encapsulate SimpleXMLElement Property
 */
class SimpleXMLProperty
{
    private $obj, $prop;
    public function __construct(SimpleXMLElement $obj, $property)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
        $this->prop = $property;
    }
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->obj->{$this->prop};
    }
    public function set($value)
    {
        $this->obj->{$this->prop} = $value;
    }
}


$xmlStr = '<root><title></title></root>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

function set_property(SimpleXMLProperty $prop)
{
   $prop->set('Test');
}

$property = new SimpleXMLProperty($xml, 'title');

set_property($property);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><title>Test</title></root>
```

It encapsulates the property and accesses it in read and write context depending on the get or set function called ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KktM3M)).

But for what you build, it might be a better thing to look into DomDocument instead. It has a much more standardized interface to the DOM, and you actually pass objects already around, like text-nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I had taken a look at DOM earlier, and it does'nt suit me. I use propel which already use SimpleXML. I think I would use your piece of code or just return the text in order to modify in calling context.
First time asking here, and very impressed, Thanks a lot for the quick answers !

Comment: Whichever suits you better. It's not specifically a SimpleXML problem, this is true for any other property as well that makes use of the overloading functions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php